# After upgrade, rc.local now gives su must be ran from a terminal in rc.local

Tags: 16.04, su

I have a few Ubuntu systems which use the su command from within the rc.local script. This updates a users git repo on the local machine, so its important that the ownership of files is kept to the correct user.

This was working before spectre/meltdown patches, but now I'm getting inconsistent results when the script runs. Some machines are able to run the su command but many say that "su must be ran from a terminal" and the script does not run.

I'm struggling to understand what has changed in the last updates that would break this.

Comment: I can't tell you what may have changed - but you might consider trying `sudo -u` in place of su

Comment: Thank you kindly, that resolved the issue. I feel rather silly for asking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure why su -s stopped working like it did before, but `sudo -u username` does resolve the issue.

I did have to chain the commands together to change directory as `sudo -u username` resets the working directory to the user's home directory:

```
sudo -S -u username -i /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /opt/bin; git reset --hard'
```